# How to retrieve range.address which is longer than 255 character?

Tags: vba, excel

I am having hard time with retrieving range.address which is longer than 255 characters.
My range consists of multiple fragmented ranges, its address looks like this: 
"A1:B3, C4, K7:T6, A3:D3"

Currently I am working on a range with address longer than 1000 characters. The sad thing is I have not been able to get the full address with range.address. I got only 255 first character.

Any help is appreciated :)

By the way, I have read Microsoft's work around on passing string longer than 255 chars at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105416 . But that's about passing string, not about returning string, so...yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize that there are limitation in range address length. Similarly to @Rory solution I loop through range areas but my solution uses function which returns long address string.

```
Function LongSelectionAddress(rngToGetAddress As Range) As String
    Dim LongAddress As String, rngArea As Range

    For Each rngArea In rngToGetAddress.Areas
        LongAddress = LongAddress & rngArea.Address & ","
    Next rngArea

    LongSelectionAddress = Left(LongAddress, Len(LongAddress) - 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what use the address would be, but you can get it by looping through the areas of the range:

```
Sub bar()
    Dim n                     As Long
    Dim rg                    As Range
    Dim rgArea                As Range
    Dim sAddress              As String

    For n = 1 To 500
        If n = 1 Then
            Set rg = Cells(n, 1)
        Else
            Set rg = Union(rg, Cells(n * 2, 1))
        End If
    Next n

    For Each rgArea In rg.Areas
        sAddress = sAddress & "," & rgArea.Address
    Next rgArea

    MsgBox Len(sAddress)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Rory for your prompt answer :)