# Getting 1004 ERROR when using double lettered columns (works for single lettered)

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a error when trying to sort these columns. My code for the single lettered columns (ie. "A7") works fine, but when I use "AA7" for instance, there is an error.

```
Sub SortSectors()
'
' SortSectors Macro
'
'

Dim rng as Range
    Set rng = Application.Range("AA7,AA17,AA23,AA33,AA51,AA77,AA101,AA114,AA123,AA131,AA143,AA153,AA178,AA189,AA205,AA212,AA226,AA237,AA241,AA248,AA258,AA263,AA269,AA280,AA292,AA299,AA362,AA376,AA381,AA388,AA404,AA411,AA419,AA427,AA435,AA448,AA467,AA479,AA519,AA545,AA554,AA563,AA573,AA578,AA598")
    Dim col As Range
    For Each col In rng.Rows
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AA" & col.Row), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        Range("AA" & col.Row).Activate
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
            .SetRange ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: [There's a limit to the length of a range address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473056/how-to-retrieve-range-address-which-is-longer-than-255-character).

Comment: thanks ben do you know of a simple way to break the script into 2?

Comment: You're just using the `.Rows` corresponding to your range... why not just build an array of row numbers?

Comment: and then just pass the array into the Application.range?

Comment: No, just loop through the elements of the array and don't even use `Range`.

Comment: im not sure what you mean do you mind sharing a sample snippet

Answer (score 1):

There's a 255-character limit to an address in `Range`... once you used `AA` as the column instead of `A`, you surpassed the limit.

But from your current code, it just looks like you need the *rows* in question; I'd do something like this (currently untested), using an array of just the row numbers:

```
Dim rowNums as Variant
rowNums = Array(7, 17, 23, 33, 51, 77) ' and so on

Dim i as Long
For i = LBound(rowNums) to Ubound(rowNums)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AA" & rowNums(i)), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .SetRange Range("AA" & rowNums(i))
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
Next
```

Note that you really should qualify what workbook/worksheet each `Range` is in/on.

Comment: Already created string can also be split into array if it is more than 255 characters?

Comment: @NareshBhople - you could, but why do that? That seems like overkill. If OP only needs the row numbers and the column is determined inside the loop, then I'd just keep the row numbers.

Comment: Yes, agreed..  Took time to understand the macro. Thanks.